# How to force/warn way devs treat class/django model

Tags: python, django, pycharm

We have a `Django` project and I came across this problem multiple times this year.

I will simplify the example:

```
class MyModel(Model):
    my_attr = ....
    ...

    def get_my_attr_safe():
        if not self.my_attr:
            return somecalculation()
        return self.my_attr
```

I want to force developers to use `get_my_attr_safe()` instead of `my_attr`.

It's a huge and complicated model.

My idea was to somehow override `__getattribute__` and raise Exception if it's called directly but I don't think this would work. Moreover, `Django`, of course needs to call sometimes `ModelFields` directly so I can't just do it this way.

I want to either raise `Exception` or make sure they will get the information that they have to use the `method` if possible.

For example I need them to use the method everywhere in templates:

```
{{ obj.get_my_attr_safe }}
```

instead of

```
{{ obj.my_attr }}
```

The solution doesn't have to be `Python`ic, maybe there is a way to do this using `PyCharm` only. It would be enough.

Comment: This seems to be against Python's Zen. As we all know, Python doesn't even have a mandatory scope restriction such as `private`, `protect` or something else. The reason is Python believes in the developers They can do the right things. So with the same Zen, I think you should provide enough document for your users, and notice them that if you don't use it in this way, what will happen etc.

Comment: Good use of PR review can be helpful here :) It seems to me it will be overkill to override `__getattribute__` or any kind of hack, for achieving something simple.

Answer (score 2):

The use of underscores might help here:

```
class MyModel(Model):

    _my_attr = None

    def get_my_attr_safe(self):
        if self._my_attr is None:
            self._my_attr = somecalculation()
        return self._my_attr

    my_attr = property(get_my_attr_safe)
```

Taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27481645/4716818)

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend overriding `__getattr__` or touch anything in `Model` class. This is the core of Django, if you do something, you might not know where the next bug will pop up. Rather than that, I think its better to use a wrapper around it to get the restrictions there. For example:

```
class YourModelWrapper(object):
    model_object = None
    restricted_fields = ['some', 'fields']

    def __init__(self, model_object):
        self.model_object =  model_object


    def __getattr__(self, name):
         if name is not in self.restricted_fields:
              return getattr(self.model_object, name)

         raise AttributeError("Use get_{}_safe() method instead".format(name)

# Usage
your_model_wrapper_obj = YourModelWrapper(YourModel.objects.first())
your_model_wrapper_obj.my_attr  # will raise exception
your_model_wrapper_obj.get_my_attr_safe()  # will return the values
```

*FYI* it will be a hassle to use this instead of actual model because there is lots of thing missing from this wrapper like queryset support. But there is a good side as well. You have said your model is very complicated, so using a wrapper might help to put some complexities from Model to Wrapper, or use it like a service.